# Blackjack Python

Tags: python, class

I am trying to figure out how to make the values of `t`, `j`, `q`, and `k` to the `int` value of `10`. Can someone explain where I went wrong with this?

```
class Card:

    def __init__(self, value , suit):
            self.value = value
            self.suit = suit

    def __repr__(self):
        return "The " + self.value + " of " + self.suit

    def intValue(self):
        if int(self.value) > 2 or int(self.value) < 9:
            return self.value
        elif str(self.value) == 'a':
            return 1
        elif str(self.value) == 'j' or str(self.value) == 'q' or str(self.value) == 'k' or str(self.value) == 't':
            return 10
```

Comment: `>2` and `<9` omits 2 and 10, which I'm pretty sure are valid cards. Anyway, you'll have to tell us _what_ went wrong before we can think about _where_ you went wrong.

Comment: I'm guessing the `t` from the last row is 10...?

Comment: IMO there is no reason to make a class for this, instead just use a tuple... `(value, suit)`. And then a `dict`, `{'a': 1, 'j': 10, 'q': 10, 'k': 10, 't': 10}`.

Comment: You can't try to do `int(self.value)` if `self.value` is something like `'j'`, `'q'`, etc.  You have to check if it's a non-number *before* trying to pass it to `int()`.  Otherwise you will get an error, just as you'd expect (what were you expecting `int('k')` to do?)

Comment: What about an ace having value 1 or 11, contingent on the total?

Comment: `int(self.value)` will raise an exception when `self.value` is a non-numeric string like 'a' or 'k'. Consider using try/except.

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with the comments about using a dictionary to represent the values, let's fix what you have.  It's mostly a matter of keeping it simple and remembering the type of your data (str) and not randomly imposing `str()` and `int()` calls when they're not needed:

```
class Card:

    def __init__(self, value, suit):
        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit

    def __repr__(self):
        return "The {} of {}".format(self.value, self.suit)

    def intValue(self):
        if self.value.isdigit():
            return int(self.value)
        elif self.value == 'a':
            return 1
        else:
            return 10
```